# Transcation rolling back for Exception which inherit RuntimeException

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

I have fast question.
If I create `Exception` which inherit `RuntimeException`, transcation(@Transactional) is rolling back then by default?

Comment: Any `RuntimeException` will roll back transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working as expected as mentioned in the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-attransactional-settings) as well.

> Any RuntimeException triggers rollback, and any checked Exception does not